# Need clarification of Value Type methods

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, value-type

Why can't the properties of a value type be modified from within its instance methods?

I have already read Apple's Swift documentation, which does not provide an exact explanation as to WHY. Yes I know that value types are copied when passed around, but what does that have to do with methods not being able to modify instance properties. However, these properties can be modified from the outside the struct.

Also, I found one or two posts similar to this one on here. Unfortunately, the answers on those are still ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to modify an instance of a struct you must use mutating keyword in front of the function definition.

```
struct Point {
var x = 0.0, y = 0.0
mutating func moveByX(deltaX: Double, y deltaY: Double) {
    x += deltaX
    y += deltaY
}
```

}

Comment: LOL. I know how to use the *mutating* keyword. It looks like everyone knows HOW to use it, but no one can explain WHY you need to use *mutating*. I know Apple says it's because they are *value types*, but that doesn't explain much at all.

Comment: Consider what a "value" is. For instance, take the value of the number 2. How would it make sense to change the value of the number 2? Same with a String, "hello" is not the same as "hallo" -- it has a different value. Immutability is a Good Thing™ for many reasons, and having value types be immutable by default Just Makes Sense™.

Comment: @cjwirth ahhh. i see. Thank you for that clarification. Now I seem to understand it now. :)